# Remote file Download via ASP.NET corrupted file

Tags: asp.net, download

I am using the code below which I have found on one of the forums to download a file in remote server. it seems it is working. However, the downloaded file is corrupted and I cannot unzip.

Do you have any idea why it is so? or if my approach is wrong, could you suggest me a better way please?

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string url = "http://server/scripts/isynch.dll?panel=AttachmentDownload&NoteSystem=SyncNotes&NoteType=Ticket&NoteId=1&Field=supp&File=DisplayList%2etxt";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();


        ////Initialize the output stream
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=" + "DisplayList.txt");
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", resp.ContentLength.ToString());

        ////Populate the output stream
        byte[] ByteBuffer = new byte[resp.ContentLength];
        Stream rs = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

        rs.Read(ByteBuffer, 0, ByteBuffer.Length);
        Response.BinaryWrite(ByteBuffer);
        Response.Flush();

        ///Cleanup
        Response.End();
        rs.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the article on http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;812406 solved my problem.     Many thanks to @Aliostad for his effort to help me.

Comment: I tried your solution AnarchistGeek but it doesnt work for me, can you post your complete aspxpage? Really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, use `application/octet-stream` as it is the standard content type for downloads.
- `new byte[resp.ContentLength + 1]` will define a buffer which is one byte larger than content type. I believe this is the reason for corruption. Use `new byte[resp.ContentLength]`.

I actually recommend re-writing it and removing memorystream:

```
        const int BufferLength = 4096;
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[BufferLength];
        Stream rs = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

        int len = 0;
        while ( (len = rs.Read(byteBuffer,0,byteBuffer.Length))>0)
        {
            if (len < BufferLength)
            {
                Response.BinaryWrite(byteBuffer.Take(len).ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                Response.BinaryWrite(byteBuffer);
            }
            Response.Flush();   


        }
```

Comment: @Aliostad thanks for reply.. it did not make any difference, the downloaded file is still corrupted...

Comment: Did you change the content type?

Comment: thanks for the update, I now get !   The archive is either in unknown format or damaged, for zip files, I tried to download a png file, and it is corrupted too. I have made the changes you mentioned. Unfortunately, it did not work...

Comment: You are reading a file from another server and right it back to response. **Where exactly this URL is?** If you use a browser and type in the URL, does it download?

Comment: it is on another intranet server, if I use this url on the browser, it downloads it.

Comment: OK, how big is the original and how big is the one received by your ASP.NET? What is the difference? You really need to provide more information.

Comment: well, I tried it with a 45 mb zip file, 7kb  png file, and 6kb txt file. the png file and zip file are corrupted, I can view the txt file but I can see almost half of the info, and [null][null] values have been added to at the end of txt file. the file sizes are same.

Comment: Can you please do me a favour? Update your question with the latest code (with the changes you have made). Cheers

Comment: I did. please see the question. Cheers

Comment: Remove this line: `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", resp.ContentLength.ToString());` we should not set the content length as header

Comment: :( nope... did not work... same result.. I tried with the txt file, and half of txt file contains [null] when I look at it on notepad++..

Comment: OK. All I can think of is that there is a proxy in between which messes things up.

Comment: if I use the MemoryStream approach which I posted first and set this line  byte[] ByteBuffer = new byte[1]; it works:) but it downloads filed in ages... do you have any idea why it is so?

Comment: @Aliostad thanks for your update. I will try it too. I found an article on MSDN and changed a bit, it seems working, I will share it in a min.. many thanks for your help.