# Download file in chunks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got the problem as below:
There is some SOAP web service which allows to read stream files. I need to read the whole file divided to chunks and transmit to user. All actions should do not block UI main thread: user presses 'Save' button on save file dialog, and is able to move on to the next page or perform another action. I will be grateful for the sample solution. Note that the solution should work with IIS 5.1.

Regards,
Jimmy

Comment: Remember: People are not going to do your work for you, but they are more than happy to help. Thus, you are much more likely to get useful responses if you describe what solutions you have been thinking about, what you have tried to implement and why that didn't work.

Comment: I do not expect that someone will write it for me. Unfortunately I can not show the existing solutions for legal reasons. Any tips or pseudocode will be very helpful.

Comment: We don't ask for your 100KB production source file, we only need a snippet that illustrates the task you're solving. Or do you think it's illegal for you too? Do your legal obligations permit posting the question on Stack Overflow? :)

Answer (score 2):

Downloading a file in ASP.NET byte-by-byte to the response page. check at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478985.aspx#aspnet-jspmig-downloadinganduploading_topic6) about this:

```
try
   {
      System.String filename = "C:\\downloadJSP\\myFile.txt";

      // set the http content type to "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM
      Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";

      // initialize the http content-disposition header to 
      // indicate a file attachment with the default filename
      // "myFile.txt"
      System.String disHeader = "Attachment;
      Filename=\"myFile.txt\"";
      Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);

      // transfer the file byte-by-byte to the response object
      System.IO.FileInfo fileToDownload = new
         System.IO.FileInfo(filename);
      System.IO.FileStream fileInputStream = new
        System.IO.FileStream(fileToDownload.FullName,
        System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
      int i;
      while ((i = fileInputStream.ReadByte()) != - 1)
      {
         Response.Write((char)i);
      }
      fileInputStream.Close();
      Response.Flush();
      Response.Close();
   }
   catch (System.Exception e)
   // file IO errors
   {
      SupportClass.WriteStackTrace(e, Console.Error);
   }
```

There are some articles that may help you to implement and solve errors:

[download an excel file from byte() on https server](http://forums.asp.net/t/1556037.aspx/1)

[asp.net downloading file from ftp getting it as byte[] then saving it as file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wspdev/thread/9a3aa798-6a6f-48e9-ab9b-a30a14ed57cf)

[Remote file Download via ASP.NET corrupted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498931/remote-file-download-via-asp-net-corrupted-file)

[Response.WriteFile cannot download a large file](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;812406)

Answer (score 0):

ProcessRequest method form downloader HttpHandler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            RequestTarget target = RequestTarget.ParseFromQueryString(context.Request.QueryString);
            Guid requestId = new Guid(context.Request.QueryString["requestId"]);
            string itemName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.QueryString["itemName"]);
            if (target != null &&
                !requestId.Equals(Guid.Empty) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemName))
            {
                HttpResponse response = context.Response;
                response.Buffer = false;
                response.Clear();
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + itemName + "\"");
                response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                int length = 100000, i = 0;
                byte[] fileBytes;
                do
                {
                    fileBytes = WS.ReadFile(requestId, target, i * length, length);
                    i++;
                    response.OutputStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                    response.Flush();
                }
                while (fileBytes != null && fileBytes.Length == length);
            }
        }
```

The whole problem is not to organize download action, but satisfy the condition that download action should do not block UI main thread: user presses 'Save' button on save file dialog, and is able to move on to the next page or perform another action. The solution written by Niranjan Kala causes, when the file is very large user isn't able to see another page until the download action has completed. I appreciate it, but it's not what I meant ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make the browser initiate a new request for the file without reloading the current page. The easiest approach is probably to just create  a link with target="_blank". Something like this should do:

```
<a href="http://yourhost/yourdownloadhandler?requestid=blah&itemName=blahblah" target="_blank">Download file</a>
```

If you provide a content type of `application/octet-stream` most browsers will save the file to disk.